# Use SQL Server trigger to update a column in another table after an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to accomplish the following using a SQL Server trigger: once a new row is inserted into a table, I would like to update a column in another table.

For example: I have a table called `Users` and a table called `Activity`. Every time a client connects to the server, a row is inserted into the `Activity` table; once the row is inserted (which contains `user_id`), I would like to update the column in the `Users` table that stores the date and time of the last activity.

```
UPDATE Users
SET Last_Activity_TimeStamp = GETDATE()
WHERE Users.User_ID = Activity.User_ID
```

But SSMS throws an error saying:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.Activity.User_ID" could not be bound

If I change the above update statement to:

```
UPDATE Users
SET Last_Activity_TimeStamp = GETDATE()
WHERE Users.User_ID = User_ID
```

All the rows in Users table are updated.

I understand that there is an `Inserted` table and that the rows are added there before they are inserted in to the main `Activity` table, however I have potentially many users connecting up and there will be many rows inserted in to `Activity` table. Potentially a 1000 per second. I would like to know how to get the `user_id` of the row being inserted in to `Activity` table and update the `Last_Activity_TimeStamp` in the `Users` table.

Edit: I guess where I am lacking the knowledge is that I do not know how many rows can be in an `Inserted` table at any time, given that in my design a single transaction only inserts a single row. Is it possible that there may be more than one row in the `Inserted` table from other active transactions since there are multiple users connecting and disconnecting?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much @marc_s for style edit, much better and clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other responses both fail to take into account that the `Inserted` pseudo table in a trigger **will contain MULTIPLE rows** at times - one should **never ever** select a single value - this will **NOT WORK** as expected if multiple rows are being inserted at once.

The trigger **must be written** in a **set-based** manner to handle this situation - which is really quite easy - try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgActivityInsert
ON [dbo].[Activity]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE u
    SET Last_Activity_TimeStamp = GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.Users u
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON u.User_Id = i.User_Id
END
```

With this, your trigger will work just fine whether you insert one, ten or a hundred rows at once, and all corresponding entries in the `dbo.User` table will be updated properly.

Comment: excellent, I have managed to do some test and you are absolutely correct. The only thing I would add is that as someone posted above, it appears that Inserted table is scoped to the trigger and since by design I only insert one row (never more) per activity per user, it will contain only one row. However, having said that, your approach is indeed the most robuts one and therefore I shall adopt it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot refer table fields like **dbo.Activity.User_ID**. Please change you trigger code like this..

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trk_Test 
    ON [dbo].[Activity]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT = 0

    SELECT @ID = [User_Id] FROM inserted

    UPDATE Users 
    SET Last_Activity_TimeStamp = GETDATE()
    WHERE [User_Id] = @Id

END
```

**Inserted and Deleted tables**
    Inserted /Deleted are the virtual table which have scope only to the trigger. You can not refer outside the trigger. So no matter how many users are connected at a time, inserted and deleted tables never conflicts.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @ID = [User_Id] FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Yes.. you are right @marc_s.. but hear in the above question, as described, there is only one row will be inserted in single transaction...

Comment: Yes - *now*, the OP says he's only inserted on row - but that *could change* in the future. Do **NOT** write code that only works under certain circumstances - especially if writing the **proper code** is so simple (as shown in my own answer)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks @marc_s